# External npm package uses dynamic imports which results in webpack problems

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have trouble bundling my JavaScript files with webpack with a NPM package which makes use of [dynamic imports](https://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

My projects `app.js` imports the following library

```
import '@raruto/leaflet-elevation/dist/leaflet-elevation';
```

[This library uses internally dynamic imports](https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-elevation/blob/master/src/control.js#L229) for lazy loading its code over HTTP requests when needed. If I try to bundle my project code with webpack I will receive errors because, webpack tries to analyze these imports.
I have already found a [solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8341#issuecomment-436550381) with the help of the comment `/* webpackIgnore: true */` but for this solution the comment needs to exist in the external npm package which I want to use.
Without this, the requests for the dynamic imports of the package ends in error messages in the browser console

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module
> 'http://localhost/src/handlers/distance.js'

So how can I tell webpack to ignore the dynamic imports of the external NPM package?

- Do I need to configure https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ for this and if yes, how do I?
- Does the NPM package need to add the `/* webpackIgnore: true */` comment for webpack users?